# Импорт CLR-сборки

Tags: sql-server

Пытаюсь импортировать CLR-сборку на SQL Server 2014.

```
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET trustworthy ON;
GO;
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO;
RECONFIGURE;
GO;
```

выполняется без ошибок, владельцы согласованы, право `Unsafe Assembly` есть, права на схему полные, роль `sysadmin` в наличии.

При импорте вылетает ошибка:

> Ошибка: Не удалось установить сборку "System.DirectoryServices", так как ее использование запрещено существующей политикой. Внимание! Регистрируемая сборка объектных структур Microsoft .NET Framework "system.directoryservices, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorarchitecture=msil." не прошла полную проверку в среде под управлением SQL Server. В дальнейшем при обновлении или обслуживании этой сборки или .NET Framework подпрограмма интеграции со средой CLR может перестать работать. Дополнительные сведения см. в электронной документации по SQL Server.

При этом на 2008 R2 все импортируется при тех же исходных. Аналогичное предупреждение высвечивает, но импортирует нормально и работает без проблем в боевых условиях.

Полностью самописные библиотеки для обращения к внешним сервисам работают и импортирутся в обоих случаях одинаково, без каких либо проблем, только с этой такая засада.

Что я мог упустить? Где находятся упомянутые политики, чтобы их можно было поправить?

Ну или если вдруг есть нормальный способ обратиться к AD для получения и проверки произвольных данных пользователя без километровых скриптов и минутных задержек не используя CLR, тоже будет неплохим вариантом.

PS: Официальную документацию перекапываю второй день, если просмотрел, просто ткните носом пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все заработало, но это было "весело".

Теперь по порядку.

Очень помогла наводка от [@minamoto](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/3171/minamoto) про версию CLR. Прямой обратной совместимости между 2.0 и 4.0 не предусмотрено, поэтому пришлось таки пересобирать проект под последнюю версию. Дальше веселее.

Чтобы получить зависимые сборки выставил в параметрах проекта создание локальной копии, собрал проект, начал импортировать в нужной последовательности и... `System.DirectoryServices` не прошла внутренний аудит CLR и отказалась импортироваться, сообщив, что в ней отсутствует код некоторых классов.

Поиски привели на [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/773083/unable-to-create-assembly-for-directoryservices-v4-0-in-sql-server-2012), `Status : Closed as By Design`

По субъективным ощущениям и размерам полученных сборок - при сборке проекта из оригинальной сборки вырезается все неиспользуемое и в таком виде кладется в выходную папку проекта.

Ок, пробуем импортировать сборки из указанной в ответе Microsft папки `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`. Ура, импорт прошел без ошибок. Импортируем функции. Пробуем выполнить... снова неудача. Но теперь уже ошибка при загрузке сборки во время выполнения, в качестве причины указывается не совпадение ключей загружаемой сборки и сборки размещенной в GAC. Причина - не совпадает версия, вероятно были обновления.

В итоге удалось найти правильные сборки в `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL`. Все импортировано, протестировано и работает как часы... вероятно до следующего обновления фреймворка.

Итог:
Использовать интеграцию CLR сборок в SQL нужно осторожно и только тогда, когда других эффективных решений не существует. У нас выбора не было, пришлось страдать.

---

[Список официально поддерживаемых Microsoft сборок для интеграции в SQL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/922672/support-policy-for-untested--net-framework-assemblies-in-the-sql-serve) -  они не требуют ручного импорта и загружаются напрямую из GAC при необходимости, список скромный, но хоть что-то.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете подключить Active Directory Service Interface как linked Server и использовать простые запросы к LDAP с использованием OPENQUERY.

Вот так создается Linked Server:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'ADSI', @srvproduct=N'Active Directory Service Interfaces', @provider=N'ADSDSOObject', @datasrc=N'adsdatasource'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'ADSI',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'DOMAIN\USER',@rmtpassword='*********'
```

Вот таким запросом он вызывается для получения данных:

```
SELECT * FROM OpenQuery ( 
  ADSI,  
  'SELECT displayName, telephoneNumber, mail, mobile, facsimileTelephoneNumber 
  FROM  ''LDAP://DOMAIN.com/OU=Players,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com'' 
  WHERE objectClass =  ''User'' 
  ') AS tblADSI
ORDORDER BY displayname
```

Подробнее можно посмотреть по этой ссылке - есть подробности использования такого подключения: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2580/querying-active-directory-data-from-sql-server/

Comment: Хорошее решение, и оно у нас уже используется, но оказалось, что не хватает некоторых возможностей, поэтому и пришлось интегрировать сборку. Альтернативы пока, к сожалению, нет.

Answer (score 2):

По поводу импорта: я не сталкивался с проблемой лично, но, насколько я понял из изучения вопроса, с SQL Server 2012 версия CLR была поднята до 4.0, а вы, как я понимаю, импортируете библиотеку CLR 2.0.

Нашел информацию по этой ссылке на английском SO, там есть несколько ссылок с вопросами, касающимися импорта сборок при апгрейде версии SQL Server:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349838/sql-server-2016-create-assembly-for-assembly-system-servicemodel-failed

Comment: спасибо за наводку, действительно отсутствует обратная совместимость между 2.0 и 4.0. Но путь импорта не проверенных сборок несколько удлинился, чуть позже распишу все недостающее.